# How to typescript a lazy loader in reactJS (with example)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, react-typescript

I am trying to convert this react js code to typescript, but I am not sure how to convert this code to typescript

I am having issues with with these two lines

```
const Shop = lazy(pageLoader(() => import("pages/report/shop")));
const Item = lazy(pageLoader(() => import("pages/report/item")));
```

I get the following error, and I am not sure what to do

```
Argument of type '() => Promise<unknown>' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => Promise<{ default: ComponentType<any>; }>'.
  Type 'Promise<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<{ default: ComponentType<any>; }>'.
    Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type '{ default: ComponentType<any>; }'.ts(2345)
```

utils

```
import i18n from "i18n";
import { ComponentType } from "react";

export const pageLoader = (
  component: () => any
) => {
  return () =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      component()
        .then((module: React.ReactNode) => resolve(module))
        .catch((error: object) => {
          alert(i18n.t("session_timeout_message"));
          window.location.href = `${process.env.REACT_APP_LOGOUT}`;
          reject(error);
        });
    });
};
```

Report

```
import { lazy, Suspense } from "react";
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import { PulseDotLoader } from "components/Loader";
import { pageLoader } from "components/Pages/utils";

const Shop = lazy(pageLoader(() => import("pages/report/shop")));
const Item = lazy(pageLoader(() => import("pages/report/item")));

const Report = () => {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<PulseDotLoader size={20} verticalPosition={"50%"} />}>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/report/shop" component={Shop} />
        <Route path="/report/item" component={Item} />
      </Switch>
    </Suspense>
  );
};

export default Report;
```